# Asp.net chart controls not loading windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, charts

I have developed MVC application with a page with asp.net chart controls and it is working fine in local. After i deployed the code in Azure, they are not loading on the page. I have around 10 charts but only 1 or 2 charts are loading randomly. Does any one had faced the same issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check in the console.log of your browser if  there is an error. If not, it means that there is a problem related to how the charts get information. (connection string for example).

My tip: create a new page with the same charts, but with fixed values (Fake List for example) and see if it works.